# Why am I getting `undefined reference to xxx` errors when all libraries and references needed are accounted for?

Tags: gcc, cmake, linker, g++, raptor2

Essentially I am trying to use the [redland rdf](http://librdf.org/) libraries but I cannot link to them. When I try a simple basic program which uses the redland libraries I get these errors:

```
/usr/local/lib/librdf.a(rdf_init.o): In function `librdf_free_memory':
/home/ciaran/Software/redland/redland-1.0.17/src/rdf_init.c:671: undefined reference to `raptor_free_memory'
/usr/local/lib/librdf.a(rdf_init.o): In function `librdf_alloc_memory':
/home/ciaran/Software/redland/redland-1.0.17/src/rdf_init.c:689: undefined reference to `raptor_alloc_memory'
/usr/local/lib/librdf.a(rdf_init.o): In function `librdf_calloc_memory':
/home/ciaran/Software/redland/redland-1.0.17/src/rdf_init.c:707: undefined reference to `raptor_calloc_memory'
```

At first glance, you might just think I have a missing link library, which is what I thought until I inspected further (see below), however, the libraries are all accounted for.

A proper minimal working example is difficult in this instance because it requires getting and building the libraries that I'm trying to use. However, I've created a GitHub [repository](https://github.com/CiaranWelsh/RedlandBuildTest)

```
$ git clone git@github.com:CiaranWelsh/RedlandBuildTest.git
```

that contains the source files necessary for building the Redland libraries as well as the example code I'm using (which breaks).

In order to build the libraries, you will also need

```
    $ sudo apt install automake autoconf libtool gtk-doc-tools
    $ sudo apt install libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt libxslt-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libltdl-dev
```

Note, I'm working on Ubuntu-18.04 on windows subsystem for Linux.

To get, build and install the libraries I'm using these terminal commands:

```
#raptor2
wget "http://download.librdf.org/source/raptor2-2.0.15.tar.gz" 
tar -xvf raptor2-2.0.15.tar.gz
cd raptor2-2.0.15
./autogen.sh 
make
sudo make install
```

```
# redland (librdf)
wget "http://download.librdf.org/source/redland-1.0.17.tar.gz" 
tar -xvf redland-1.0.17.tar.gz
cd redland-1.0.17 
./autogen.sh
make
sudo make install
```

```
# rasqal
wget "http://download.librdf.org/source/rasqal-0.9.33.tar.gz" 
tar -xvf rasqal-0.9.33.tar.gz
cd rasqal-0.9.33
./autogen.sh 
make 
sudo make install
```

Which are available in the github repository as shell scripts (`get-raptor.sh`, `get-rasqal.sh` and `get-librdf.sh`).

And my minimal CMake script (also in the repository):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(RedlandBuildTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_library(RAPTOR2_STATIC_LIBRARY
        NAMES libraptor2.a
        PATHS /usr/local/lib
        )

find_path(RAPTOR2_INCLUDE_DIR
        NAMES raptor2.h
        PATHS /usr/local/include/raptor2
        )
find_library(RASQAL_STATIC_LIBRARY
        NAMES librasqal.a
        PATHS /usr/local/lib
        )

find_path(RASQAL_INCLUDE_DIR
        NAMES rasqal.h
        PATHS /usr/local/include/rasqal
        )

find_library(LIBRDF_STATIC_LIBRARY
        NAMES librdf.a
        PATHS /usr/local/lib
        )

find_path(LIBRDF_INCLUDE_DIR
        NAMES librdf.h
        PATHS /usr/local/include
        )

add_executable(RedlandBuildTest main.c)

target_include_directories(RedlandBuildTest PRIVATE
        ${RAPTOR2_INCLUDE_DIR}
        ${RASQAL_INCLUDE_DIR}
        ${LIBRDF_INCLUDE_DIR}
        )

target_link_libraries(RedlandBuildTest PRIVATE
        ${RAPTOR2_STATIC_LIBRARY}
        ${RASQAL_STATIC_LIBRARY}
        ${LIBRDF_STATIC_LIBRARY}
        curl
        xml2
        xslt
        ltdl
        )

get_target_property(LINK_LIBRARIES RedlandBuildTest LINK_LIBRARIES)
get_target_property(INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES RedlandBuildTest INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)

message(STATUS "

LINK_LIBRARIES      ${LINK_LIBRARIES}
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}

")

message(STATUS "

    RAPTOR2_STATIC_LIBRARY   ${RAPTOR2_STATIC_LIBRARY}
    RAPTOR2_INCLUDE_DIR      ${RAPTOR2_INCLUDE_DIR}

    RASQAL_STATIC_LIBRARY    ${RASQAL_STATIC_LIBRARY}
    RASQAL_INCLUDE_DIR       ${RASQAL_INCLUDE_DIR}

    LIBRDF_STATIC_LIBRARY    ${LIBRDF_STATIC_LIBRARY}
    LIBRDF_INCLUDE_DIR       ${LIBRDF_INCLUDE_DIR}

")
```

And the output of the CMake command:

```
#(looks good)
LINK_LIBRARIES      /usr/local/lib/libraptor2.a;/usr/local/lib/librasqal.a;/usr/local/lib/librdf.a;curl;xml2;xslt;ltdl 
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES /usr/local/include/raptor2;/usr/local/include/rasqal;/usr/local/include


    RAPTOR2_STATIC_LIBRARY   /usr/local/lib/libraptor2.a
    RAPTOR2_INCLUDE_DIR      /usr/local/include/raptor2

    RASQAL_STATIC_LIBRARY    /usr/local/lib/librasqal.a
    RASQAL_INCLUDE_DIR       /usr/local/include/rasqal

    LIBRDF_STATIC_LIBRARY    /usr/local/lib/librdf.a
    LIBRDF_INCLUDE_DIR       /usr/local/include
```

To build, I'm using CLion which just does this in the background:

```
mkdir build && cd build
CMake ..
make
```

Thus giving me linker errors. I have dug a little deeper by using `nm` to inspect the contents of the Redland libraries.

```
$nm -A librdf.a > librdf.a.nmoutput.txt
$nm -A libraptor2.a > libraptor2.a.nmoutput.txt
$nm -A librasqal.a > librasqal.a.nmoutput.txt
```

The first offending `undfined reference` error

```
/usr/local/lib/librdf.a(rdf_init.o): In function `librdf_free_memory':
/home/ciaran/Software/redland/redland-1.0.17/src/rdf_init.c:671: undefined reference to `raptor_free_memory'
```

is in function `librdf_free_memory`, which is a defined reference inside `librdf.a`

```
# librdf.a.nmoutput.txt
...
librdf.a:rdf_init.o:0000000000000740 T librdf_free_memory
...
```

When we look for the undefined reference to `raptor_free_memory`, we se that it is indeed undefined inside `librdf.a.`.

```
#librdf.a.nmoutput.txt
...
librdf.a:rdf_init.o:                 U raptor_free_memory
...
```

But this should be in `libraptor2.a` anyway, and if we look we see that it is indeed there and defined as it should be:

```
# libraptor2.a.nmoutput.txt
...
libraptor2.a:raptor_general.o:0000000000000863 T raptor_free_memory
...
```

My understanding is that the process of linking should essentially fill the undefined reference inside `librdf.a` with the definition inside `libraptor.a`, but this clearly is not happening.

Why is this happening?

Comment: I didn't go into detilas of all your information, but note that the _order_ in which objects and libraries are specified is important. The linker searches for symbols from left-to-right in the objects and libraries specified on the linker command line.

Comment: Feedback: people will read "First of all, I appreciate that this is a long post, but I've been stuck on this problem for days now and would really like to get some help" and interpret it as unseemly begging. There are hundreds of thousands of "please halp me :_("  posts on this site and they are usually downvoted and/or closed. There is a desire on Stack Overflow for succinct, technical writing, and thus pleading material intended to tug on the heartstrings generally makes no difference, and it's probably inappropriate anyway, given that readers are volunteers.

Comment: @halfer no problem, fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your static libraries have dependencies on each other, the link order **matters** (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/409470/3987854) response).

If `librdf` depends on the `libraptor` library (as indicated by the link error), the `libraptor` library should be listed *after* `librdf` when specified to the linker. Try re-arranging the list of libraries in your `target_link_libraries()` command to adhere to this ordering, based on your library dependencies.